# jqGrid: format cell value without changing actual (underlying) value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Is that possible to **display** something other, yet keeping the **original** cell value for editing purposes?

one of the columns in my jqGrid is 'enumerated' data. For editing I'm providing edittype: select + editoptions: *enum-key:label* set, which results in properly displayed *select* editor. However I'd like to display the *label* instead of *enum-key* for regular view, not only editing. I know I could use custom cell formatters but that would cause the **actual value** to be **changed**, then I'd have to lookup the keys-labels pairs again before editing the row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing some code, but you shouldn't need to use a custom formatter, just use `formatter: 'select'` as shown in the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter).  It specifically states that "the data should contain the keys (“1” or “2”), but the value (“One”, or “Two”) will be displayed in the grid".

Another option if you need more control over the output is to use the `buildSelect` option of editoptions.  For example, here is a select that I have in code, there are other examples out there too.  The idea of course is that you can return any data and then manipulate it as needed to build the select.  The data event change function then makes sure that the correct value is set for the input field.

```
{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true, hidden: true,  
     editoptions: { defaultValue: row_id,
                    dataUrl: "DataService.asmx/GetList",
                    buildSelect: function (data) {
                                 var s = '<select>';
                                 if (data && data.d) {
                                    //data is nested, so we need a few steps to get to the actual data
                                    var list = data.d;
                                    var opts = JSON.parse(list);
                                    var subList = opts.List;
                                    //loop through the data to build the options list
                                    for (var i = 0, l = subList.length; i < l; i++) 
                                        {   var ri = subList[i]; 
                                            s += '<option value=' + ri.Id + '>' + ri.Name + '</option>';
                                        }
                                  }
                                  else {
                                     s+= "<option value=0>No data to display</option>";
                                  }
                                  return s + "</select>"; 
                            } ,
                      dataEvents: [
                              { type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                        $('input#Id').val(this.value);
                                }
                              }
                              ]

                     },
       editrules:  {edithidden: true},
       edittype: 'select'
```

}